# Can I add trusted certificate to Visual Studio Android Emulator?

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, http-proxy

There is a blog post at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/05/06/using-fiddler-to-monitor-network-traffic-from-the-vs-emulator-for-android/ which describes how to monitor network traffic from Visual Studio emulator for Android. In this post it is said that

> If you have HTTPS traffic decryption on (under the HTTPS tab in Fiddler Options), Android will display a certificate warning.

Is it possible to add trusted certificate from HTTP Proxy to Android emulator?